# SKU Usage Per Session Or Per Object/Point On My Map?

Tags: google-maps, google-app-engine

I wish Google can break it down explaining this.

Says, if I was a manager with no developing code experience, there is no way that I could get the answer from Google support with the information provided for everyone.

I just don't understand how SKU usage work. Is it per point on a map that need SKU? Is it per whole set of points? If I have 30 points on my road destination, does that means that I used 30 SKU?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ***Google Maps Platform APIs***, please know that it uses a *pay-as-you-go pricing model* -  meaning all APIs under Google Map Platform are billed by **SKU**.    **SKU** is a combination of '*Product API*'  and  '*Service or Function you used*'. Each combination has a price and cost is calculated by *SKU Usage x Price per each use*.

So you will be billed depending on which services you are using. You can learn more about this on this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing).

If you have more specific question with your project and to open a more personalized channel, I suggest that you [create a support case](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#creating-a-support-case) to reach out with the support team.